# Vuejs - keep-alive component toggled with v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, preprocessor-directive

#### The Problem

I have a child component that may or may not exist on the page with a `v-if`.  Trying to keep it cached when the user has clicked other things so that search terms and whatnot show up again when the user returns fails no matter how I try to cache with `<keep-alive>`.

#### What I've tried

The [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) seems to indicate that all I need to do is wrap my component in a `<keep-alive>` tag and things should just work.  I tried matching some documentation that uses the `<component>` tag which clearly doesn't work.  I also tried using the `include` prop since just wrapping it doesn't work.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>child: {{text}}<div>',
  data() {return {text: ""}},
  created(){
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.text = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100)}`
  })
},
  activated: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('in activated');
    });
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      showNow:false,
      message: 'This is a test.'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeText: function() {
      this.message = 'changed';
    },
    toggle() {
      this.showNow = !this.showNow
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <keep-alive include="child">
    <div v-if="showNow">
        <h4>Title of section to be toggled</h4>
        <component is="child"></component>
    </div>
  </keep-alive>
  
  <button @click="toggle()">toggle child</button>
</div>
```

I've also tried not using `include` and just wrapping like so `<keep-alive><child></child></keep-alive>` or using the `<component>` syntax and neither of those work either.

If you remove the conditional rendering, the `activated` hook is called, but that obviously defeats the purpose of `<keep-alive>`!  As it stands right now, that hook is never called, which is frustrating.

Also, [the example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) in the documentation doesn't help either because they're not using `v-if`, just changing which components are rendered via a string....

P.S. I have no idea how to tag this other than Vue.js

Comment: I'm not sure but if you use `v-if`, the element exists or not when you load the page and can't change without reloading the page. Did you try `v-show` instead ?

Comment: `v-show` doesn't work for my case because the data hasn't been loaded yet - it throws a bunch of console errors because things don't exist.  I specifically want `<keep-alive>` to be caching data for an element not currently rendered in the DOM, but it seems like that's not what it's supposed to be used for.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a lightly modified version of your code with `keep-alive` working correctly:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>child: {{text}}</div>',
  data() {return {text: ""}},
  created(){
    console.log('in created')
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.text = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 100)}`
    })
  },
  activated: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
     console.log('in activated');
    });
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      showNow:false,
      message: 'This is a test.'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeText: function() {
      this.message = 'changed';
    },
    toggle() {
      this.showNow = !this.showNow
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <keep-alive>
    <child v-if="showNow"></child>
  </keep-alive>
  
  <button @click="toggle()">toggle child</button>
</div>
```

The `created` hook is only called the first time. On subsequent activation the `activated` hook is called but not `created`.

The key change is that the `<child>` component must be a direct child of `<keep-alive>`. This direct child must also be the component that has the `v-if`.

You can't use a `<div>` for this purpose as `<keep-alive>` specifically looks for a component, not just an element. See:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ec78fc8b6d03e59da669be1adf4b4b5abf670a34/src/core/components/keep-alive.js#L85

Another common mistake with `keep-alive` is to put a `v-if` on the `keep-alive` component itself, or on one of its ancestors. This won't work as the `keep-alive` component itself will be destroyed. The `keep-alive` component maintains a cache of child components but if the `keep-alive` is itself destroyed then that cache is lost.

Comment: Does `<keep-alive>` cache once it's in the DOM?  Like if I wrap the the `<keep-alive>` in a `v-if` based on lazy loaded data (something that will stay true once it's done loading), will it start caching once the ancestral conditional is true?

Comment: @dlkulp The DOM isn't really the right level of abstraction here, it's based on VNodes. That said, the answer to your question is yes. The key thing to understand is that the cache lives on the instance of the `keep-alive` component. So long as you don't destroy that component the cache will be maintained. If you don't create it initially due to an ancestral `v-if` that's no problem, the caching will begin once the `keep-alive` is created.